# Bootstrap container class not working on Chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I am having a few issues with the Google Chrome browser and Bootstrap.

1. I have a container inside of one of my HTML sections that is
   centering content in every browser except for Google Chrome.
2. It appears to be behaving as if it is a container-fluid because
   it is not spanning 100% of the viewport window, it appears to have
   about 5px of margin on the left and right side. Again, only in
   Chrome.

Here is my Code for just that section:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hD djZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,400italic,300italic,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<section id="aboutUs">
    <div class ="groupImg">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>About Us</h1>
                <p class = "motto col-md-12"><i>
                    “As a multicultural dance company, C.O.D.A. prides itself in the versatility of dance styles and creative ideas within the company. Understanding the authenticity and history of Hip Hop, we embrace all styles including street, footworking, house, breakdancing, popping, locking, tutting, freestyling, new school, old school and more. With dancers that come from both trained and untrained backgrounds, we can appreciate the possession of raw talent and acknowledge the importance of discipline and training. C.O.D.A. aims to share the common interest of Hip Hop to all people and to demonstrate a mutual understanding and respect for other dancers alike.”</i>
                </p>
            </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#aboutUs h1 {
    color:white;
    font-size:40px;
    padding: 40px 0px 20px 0px;
    text-align: center; 
    text-transform: uppercase;

}

.motto{
    color:white;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 2.0em;
    text-align: center;
}

.groupImg {
    background-image: url("img/5color_maroon.jpg");
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 750px;

}
```

Here are screenshots in each browser:

[Here is what it looks like in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtmmQ.jpg)

[Here is what it looks like in Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wD2ko.jpg)

[Here is what it looks like in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4QPj.jpg)

Didn't I have linked it correctly or am I missing something?
Thanks!

Comment: [It's working fine in Chrome for me](https://jsfiddle.net/fs66pxkn/). Are you sure something in you `main.css` isn't causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your CDN reference, with current CDN code. you may use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">` its working. or may be your main.css is having any mistake.

Comment: but i tried that there is something different in cdn code, thts why suggested.

Comment: They should be the same file. Though I do see that the `integrity` string has been modified somehow in the OP's post. Where it should be `8hDDdjZl` it's `8hD djZl`. Not sure if that would be an issue or not.

Comment: But if it was an issue with my main.css file, wouldn't it be an issue in Safari and Firefox as well?

Comment: @newman that depends on the issue. More than likely it wouldn't but without seeing the file or a live example where main.css is being used we cannot know for sure.

Comment: @hungerstar i suggested here that what i really tried, this worked on my pc, so i found the mistake in CDN code